# Button OnClick event with Bootstrap not working on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, mobile-safari

I've uploaded an example of the problem to http://jsfiddle.net/d01sm5gL/2/

The `onclick` event fires correctly on desktop browsers, but using iOS8, the event doesn't fire. I can manually call the function (using the console debugger), and it works, so I know the problem lies with bootstrap somewhere. If I use a standard button, without the bootstrap framework, it works fine.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Works fine on my iPhone 6, iOS 8.1.2. But on iPad 4 with 8.1.2, the hidden "share" menu from the jsfiddle header is grabbing the events instead - very strange. Are you on iPhone or iPad?

Comment: Also, trying to open the jsfiddle "share" menu appears to do nothing. Do you have the same problem outside of jsfiddle, or could it be a clash between jsfiddle and your script/bootstrap?

Comment: iPhone 6, 8.1.3 - Potentially that's the issue. However, when zooming in, it does in fact work. But in my original project, it doesn't :(. No idea how to debug that, because I can't post the link here. I heard one fix is to put "cursor:pointer;" in the css for the element, but this doesn't fix it either. I feel as though the latest 8.x release has broken that fix

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle works for me in iOS 8 with Safari.

Comment: Can I ask what version of iOS8 you're using?

Comment: And iPhone/iPod or iPad?

Comment: iOS 8.1.2, and iPhone 6